# npm install opensea-js failed

Tags: node.js, npm

Git-2.36.0,node-v16.15.0

1297 error code 128
1298 error Command failed: git clone --depth=1 -q -b upgrade-wyvern-js https://github.com/ProjectOpenSea/wyvern-schemas.git C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_cacache\tmp\git-clone-5a9fe46a --config core.longpaths=true
1298 error warning: templates not found in C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pacote-git-template-tmp\git-clone-0315a992
1298 error fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/ProjectOpenSea/wyvern-schemas.git/': OpenSSL SSL_read: Connection was reset, errno 10054

yarn install

Error: Command failed.
Exit code: 128
Command: git
Arguments: ls-remote --tags --heads https://github.com/ProjectOpenSea/wyvern-js.git
Directory: E:\h5\opensea
Output:
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/ProjectOpenSea/wyvern-js.git/': OpenSSL SSL_read: Connection was reset, errno 10054
at ProcessTermError.ExtendableBuiltin (C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yarn\lib\cli.js:721:66)
at ProcessTermError.MessageError (C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yarn\lib\cli.js:750:123)
at new ProcessTermError (C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yarn\lib\cli.js:790:113)
at ChildProcess. (C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yarn\lib\cli.js:25783:17)
at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:376:20)
at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1055:16)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:288:5)
Error: Command failed.
Exit code: 128
Command: git
Arguments: ls-remote --tags --heads https://github.com/ProjectWyvern/ethereumjs-abi.git
Directory: E:\h5\opensea
Output:
error: RPC failed; curl 28 OpenSSL SSL_read: Connection was reset, errno 10054

Answer (score 0, accepted):

installed successfully
Git-2.36.0
node-v16.15.0
"opensea-js": "^1.2.8"
"web3":"^1.7.0"